# Unable to download the @react-navigation/stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

When I tried to `$npm install @react-navigation/stack` it gives me an error:

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\SUJEET\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-16T07_45_16_354Z-debug.log

I tried it with all the versions but still got same error.

***debug.log file:***

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',`
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '@react-navigation/stack'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose npm-session 12c3d04c798636b8
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-navigation%2fstack 2464ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @react-navigation/stack@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...JuDiO3agYFfEvHWaX1sKH'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 3681ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...JuDiO3agYFfEvHWaX1sKH'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\SUJEET\Desktop\project\simple\firse
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@react-navigation/stack"
15 verbose node v12.16.3
16 verbose npm  v6.14.4
17 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...JuDiO3agYFfEvHWaX1sKH'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can anybody tell me what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably related to the cache used by `npm`.

Clean the cache before trying to install your package again

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install @react-navigation/stack
```

Comment: Thanks for your support it works pretty well for me.